# virtualenv com kivy

Tags: python, virtualenv

Utilizando o Ubuntu 16.04, instalei o virtualenv e criei um ambiente virtual.

Nesse ambiente virtual instalei o Cython utilizando:

```
pip install cython==0.23
```

Mando instalar o Kivy:

```
pip install kivy
```

Só que retorna um monte de erros, dentre eles:

```
/tmp/pip-build-RTmWI8/kivy/kivy/graphics/opengl.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/home/usuario/testeKivy/teste1/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-RTmWI8/kivy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZZtk3g-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/usuario/testeKivy/teste1/include/site/python2.7/kivy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-RTmWI8/
```

Quais dependências estão faltando?

Comment: Mas isso resolve o problema das dependências no ambiente virtual?

Comment: Fiz isso e mesmo assim continuo com problemas para utilizar o kivy no ambiente virtual. Mais alguma ideia/sugestão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, após aprender um pouco mais lendo os comentários, percebi que resolver o problema das dependências era "fácil".

O próprio [site oficial do Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) fornecia as informações necessárias. O que me deixava confuso era ter que instalar pacotes no sistema (global) se minha intenção era utilizar o Kivy em um ambiente virtual com `virtualenv`. Quando aprendi que era necessário instalar pacotes globalmente para que o Kivy pudesse funcionar (mesmo que no ambiente virtual), bastou seguir a [lista de instalação](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#dependencies-with-sdl2):

```
sudo apt-get install -y \
    python-pip \
    build-essential \
    git \
    python \
    python-dev \
    ffmpeg \
    libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev \
    libsdl2-mixer-dev \
    libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libportmidi-dev \
    libswscale-dev \
    libavformat-dev \
    libavcodec-dev \
    zlib1g-dev
```

A partir daí, acessei o ambiente virtual, que já havia criado com o `virtualenv`, e executei os comandos:

```
pip install cython==0.23
pip install kivy
```

E pronto! Muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos que colaboraram com meu aprendizado. Abraços.

Answer (score 1):

Então - o PIP dentro e um virtualenv resolve todas as depêndencias de pacotes Python lá dentro - mas alguns pacotes Python dependem de compilar código C para sua instalação, outros dependem de bibliotecas nativas do sistema -  e isso independe de estarem dentro do Virtualenv. (Sim, é até possível colocar biblitoecas nativas em C em versões diferentes, dentro do virtualenv, mas em geral não é necessário).

No caso, você tem que completar a instalação do Ubuntu com  as ferramentas necessárias para compilação de software - comece com `apt-get install build-essential` - e já aproveite e engrene um `apt-get build-dep python python-kivy`. Você pode ter que instalar os `build-dep` para alguns outros pacotes que desejar instalar dentro do vitualenv também) - o comando especial `build-dep` do APT trás todas os pacotes - inclusive os "*dev" necessários para compilar o pacote alvo a partir dos fontes - se fosse usado o pacote do sistema. Mesmo que dentro de um virtualenv você não esteja compilando uma library qye vai ficar disponível para o sistema todo, as depêndencias dela são as mesmas - e ela aproveita as dependências instaladas no sistema.

(Em outras distruibuições Linux, a idéia é a mesma - no fedora por exemplo, o comando para instalar as depêndencias de um pacote é `dnf builddep <pacote>`)

Comment: Então @jsbueno , a questão é que eu instalei o kivy utilizando o `sudo apt install python-kivy` e tudo funciona perfeitamente, fora do ambiente virtual, o que me leva a crer que as dependências estão instaladas. Já no ambiente virtual, não consigo executar nenhum código kivy, sempre retorna os erros que mencionei na pergunta.

Comment: Não - é exatametne como eu escrevi - quando você faz um `apt-get install python-kivy`  ( e mesmo o python-kivy-dev) - ele instala a versão pré-compilada - não os recursos que o sistema precisa para compilar o kivy. Quando você faz um "pip install" no virtulenv ele baixa o código fonte para compilar oskivy na sua máquina - e ai, as ferramentas e biblitoecas necessárias tem que estar instaladas no sistema.

Comment: Estou começando a compreender qual o funcionamento @jsbueno . Obrigado pela ajuda. Agora, ao executar o `apt-get build-dep python python-kivy` me deparo com o retorno `E: Você deve colocar algumas URIs 'source' em seu sources.list`. Mais alguma informação?

Answer (score -2):

Então, eu passei por esses problemas, instalando e testando o funcionamento, esse foi o processo que passei para conseguir utilizar o kivy e compilar o mesmo para mobile.
Criei um tutorial o qual esta funcional.

[LINK GITHUB](https://github.com/zPASP/Utilizar-Buildozer)

e pronto só executar o seu programa e compilar!